# UnityContainer Resolve new instance issue

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have this IoC-class:

```
public static class IoC
{
    private static IUnityContainer container;

    private static void setupIoC()
    {
        container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<MessageContext>(
            new InjectionConstructor(
                 new DatabaseRepository<Message>(new RepositoryConfig() {AutoDetectionEnabled = false})));

    }

    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            setupIoC();
        }
        return container.Resolve<T>();
    }
}
```

In my ViewModel I have:

```
public MessageViewModel()
    : base(Resources.MENU_BAR_COREDATA_MESSAGE)
{
    msgContext = IoC.Resolve<MessageContext>();
}
```

the msgContext is an Entity Framework abstraction... If I load an usercontrol more than one time, the repository has some entries in DbSet.Local. If I write

```
public MessageViewModel()
    : base(Resources.MENU_BAR_COREDATA_MESSAGE)
{
    msgContext = new MessageContext(new DatabaseRepository<Message>(new RepositoryConfig(){AutoDetectionEnabled = false}));
}
```

I always have a fresh new msgContext without any DbSet.Local entries etc... In my opinion its an indicator that my IoC doesn't give me a new instace when I resolve it. I use the UnityContainer and the documentation says that it always returns a new instance by default...

So I don't know why it doesn't work as I would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the injection constructor with injection factory:

```
   container.RegisterType<MessageContext>(
        new InjectionFactory( c =>
             new MessageContext(
                   new DatabaseRepository<Message>(
                         new RepositoryConfig(){AutoDetectionEnabled = false} ) ) );
```

The difference is that the factory method is executed everytime the instance is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

[When is the Unity InjectionConstructor acually run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031372/when-is-the-unity-injectionconstructor-acually-run)

I think `new DatabaseRepository` is called only once during registration

Comment: Hey Makubex, thank you for your link. But I have some trouble with the {AutoDetectionEnabled = false} how should I write that? If I use typeof(RepositoryConfig) I can't set AutoDetection...